# Vertical align an image in a div

Tags: html, css

I've seen multiple questions about a pretty simple task: how to vertically align an image in a div.

My code (http://jsfiddle.net/3cYtX/1/) is pretty simple:

```
.container {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color: green;    
}
img.middle {    
    vertical-align:middle;
}
<div class="container">
    <img class="middle" src="test.gif" width="80" height="40" />
</div>
```

My code **does not** align the image. How to fix it?

Comment: **I've seen, but didn't find an answer!**

Comment: I can't believe that all of these answers didn't work for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-vertically-align-an-image-inside-div

Comment: @MatthewLock: as you can see, the accepted answer is different that in the solution you pointed out...

Comment: No it's on that page, look http://stackoverflow.com/a/7337378/74585 you should have just tried that and voted that answer up instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the div behave like a table cell:

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/3cYtX/5/***

```
.container {
    display: table-cell; /* make it behave like a table cell */
    vertical-align: middle; /* make it align contents vertically */
    text-align: center; /* make it align contents horizontally */
}
```

Note: As James pointed out in the comments, elements set to `table-cell` should ideally be content of elements with display `table` or `table-row`.  e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/3cYtX/8/

Comment: tahnks, no need to align horizontally :)

Comment: Elements set to display as `table-cell` should ideally always be wrapped in an element set to display as `table`. The reason I used `line-height` in my answer was because with this as it currently stands you'll run into issues if you ever need to use percentage widths instead of fixed widths. Here is a demo showing what happens when you give the `.container` element 100% width: http://jsfiddle.net/3cYtX/6/.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing that out @James. Adding that bit to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`img` elements are `inline` content. This means you can simply give your `.container` element a `line-height` equal to the `height` and central text alignment:

```css
.container {
    ...

    line-height: 200px;    /* Because height is 200px. */
    text-align: center;  
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3cYtX/3/).

Comment: `line-height` also doesn't work too well with images. See this: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/3cYtX/9/ .

Comment: @abhitalks that's because you've removed the `vertical-align` from the `img` element (which features in OP's question). http://jsfiddle.net/3cYtX/10/

Comment: that was the fiddle from your answer: http://jsfiddle.net/3cYtX/3/. you may want to update that link.

Answer (score 0):

```
.container{
     vertical-align:  middle;
     text-align:      center;
     line-height:     200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It only vertically aligns if it is a table cell: [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)

```
.container {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

There are other ways to do it: [Link](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/)

```
.element {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%); /* Sorry had */ 
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);     /* to add these, then */
  transform: translateY(-50%);         /* it should center perfectly */                  
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6hB56/)

Also, this was mentioned to be [important](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/#update): *"As a few people have pointed out, this method can cause elements to be blurry due to the element being placed on a “half pixel”. A solution for this is to set its parent element to preserve-3d. Like following:"*

```
.parent-element {
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to add the `-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;` to its parent, otherwise it will *"..be blurry due to the element being placed on a “half pixel”.."*

Comment: second solution will place the left upper corner of the picture in the middle, not the picture in the middle....

Comment: @serhio there we go, it should work now.

Comment: @abhitalks yep, gotta add that to the parent element.